# Does zero-length matches end the match procedure?

Tags: java, regex

If I have a regex `a?` and a string `a`, I will get:

```
Enter your regex: a?
Enter input string to search: a
I found the text "a" starting at index 0 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
```

The match procedure ends after a zero-length match. Otherwise I will get infinite:

```
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
.....
```

My question is, does Zero-Length Matches always end the match procedure? Is there any other situation?

Comment: Apparently it does as long as the pattern accepts a zero-length string at the rightmost position where a match is possible. Remove question mark from your regex and you'll only get a single match "a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, does Zero-Length Matches always end the match
>   procedure?

No, your input string is made up of one single character `a` so it matches one zero-length position right after it, more characters lead into more matches.

> The match procedure ends after a zero-length match. Otherwise I will
>   get infinite.

It's up to RegEx engine. Different flavors handle zero-length matches in different ways. They don't let infinite matches at same position happen though:

> Perl , PCRE is to always start the next match attempt at the end of
>   the previous match, regardless of whether it was zero-length or not...
>
> Python advances after zero-length matches. The gsub() function to
>   search-and-replace skips zero-length matches at the position where the
>   previous non-zero-length match ended.

[**More on zero-length matches**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html)

Comment: Can you please give me an exmaple in Java the match procedure continues after a zero-lengh match? I'm confused about it.